# Why label and listbox in GWT are not giving scrolling effect in IE 11 and other version but it work fine in firefox and google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, gwt, listbox, label

I have created vertical panel added label and listbox over it. when i use chrome or firefox and the no of entries in listbox or lable is more than its height. it enables scrolling in order to see all the entries but IE do not show same effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [widget addesd on VerticalPanel of GWT like lable, listbox are not scroll on IE 11 and other version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669018/widget-addesd-on-verticalpanel-of-gwt-like-lable-listbox-are-not-scroll-on-ie-1)

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same question as your previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669018/widget-addesd-on-verticalpanel-of-gwt-like-lable-listbox-are-not-scroll-on-ie-1

Comment: if you have any answer related to any question then please help